# The local variable might not have been initialized - Detect unchecked exception throw within a method

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors, unchecked

I have some code with this structure:

```
public void method() {
    Object o;
    try {
        o = new Object();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Processing, several lines
        throw new Error(); //Our own unchecked exception
    }
    doSomething(o);
}
```

I have quite a few methods in which I have the same code in the catch block, so I want to extract it to a method so that I can save some lines. My problem is, that if I do that, I get a compiler error "
The local variable o might not have been initialized".

```
public void method() {
    Object o;
    try {
        o = new Object();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        handleError();
    }
    //doSomething(o); compiler error
}


private void handleError() throws Error {
    //Processing, several lines
    throw new Error();
}
```

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Note:Instance variable not need to initialize but the local variable(variable inside a method) need to initialize

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to initialize local variables before they are used as below

```
public void method() {
    Object o=null;
    try {
        o = new Object();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        handleError();
    }
   doSomething(o); 
}
```

You will not get the compilation failure until you use local variable which was not initialized

Comment: Not really suitable if the variable has to be final for some reason. In this case I would favor the solution provided by @gyro-gearless.

Comment: This feels so gross. Is there no better style?

Answer (score 5):

Since `o` is getting initialized within the `try` block and initializing `o` might throw an exception, java thinks that `doSomething(o)` statement might reach without `o` being initialized. So java wants `o` to be initialized incase `new Object()` throws exception.

So initializing `o` with `null` will fix the issue

```
public void method() {
    Object o = null;
    try {
        o = new Object(); //--> If new Object() throws exception then o remains uninitialized
    } catch (Exception e) {
        handleError();
    }
    if(o != null)
      doSomething(o);
}
```

Comment: I'd consider this an anti-pattern, as it clutters the code with unnecessary if-not-null checks! The try/catch mechanism is there to avoid such pattern: if the creation of some required objects fails, the function should leave through an exception.

Comment: True, i agree. My intention was to give the solution and explain why we get error

Answer (score 4):

Initialize your object: `Object o = null;`, however watch out for the `NullPointerException`s that might be thrown when you give it to the method calls.

Answer (score 3):

Just put the `doSomething(o)` inside the `try { }` block:

```
public void method() {
    Object o;
    try {
        o = new Object();
        doSomething(o);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        handleError();
    }

}
```

You perhaps dont want to execute doSomething() if the creation of your Object fails!

Answer (score 0):

Instance variable is the Object type so you should initialize value "null"

```
public void method() {
Object o=null;
try {
    o = new Object();
} catch (Exception e) {
    handleError();
}
doSomething(o); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because compiler doesn't know if `handlerError` always throws the `Error`. For example, there can be a logic in `handleError` method that makes it returns before throwing exception.

If you want to extract error handling into method, you can do this in this way:

```
public void method() {
    Object o;
    try {
        o = new Object();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw handleError();
    }
    System.out.println(o);
}


private Error handleError() {
    //Processing, several lines
    return new Error();
}
```

Now the compiler sees the `throw` word in catch block, and it is sure that the exception will be thrown.